# where do you define Exception hierarchy

Tags: java

where do you define your Exception hierarchy in Java?

My main question concerns package location where they your Exception must be defined.

at interface :

```
public interface IMetier {

    public void addCategorie(Categorie categorie) throws Exception;
}
```

or at package view with try and catch ?

Comment: You should only really throw such a generic `Exception` when there isn't really any other option.

Comment: Wherever the exception is most likely to occur.

Comment: You define a new exception class in the package that defines the exception.  Generally this will be the *throwing* package, or a related one.  You shouldn't (and generally can't) use a `java.*` package, nor a package name not "belonging" to your app.

Comment: Ie, if your app is in package `com.myapps.someapp`, an exception you "invent" should be defined there as well, and have that package name.

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply delegates the exception handling to the calling method.

There is no *right* answer.

- Either your code is a component in itself, then it should handle an exception internally.
- Or you are writing a re-usable library which lets the programer decide how to cope with an error/exception.

Comment: i.e. "handle or declare", right?

Comment: Yep, that's right.
Handle (try, except) or declare (throws...)

The original question is somehow not realy clear, though